# Maximum weight on a brick wall (not brackets)

Tags: walls, brick, shelving

I’m looking to put up about 14 metres of bookshelves (5 separate shelves between 1.2metres and 3.5 metres) on a wall (brick wall/masonry) built in the 50s using approx 32 strong brackets in the attic (no steel in the floor that I can detect). Not an earthquake prone area. It’s a terraced red brick house (so not concrete to my knowledge)

Wall height: approx 230cm tall, triangular at the top to a pitched roof with a 1cm down to 2.22cm incline and equidistant.

The bottom 1m 20cm is straight walls.

Wall is in good knick, signs of the previous owner having drilled into it before in multiple places.

Looking to place shelves getting longer and longer going down the wall with a 35cm or so gap vertically between them eg.

```
- 



—-



———



———



———
```

Small beams about 60mm squared at the edges of the third shelf from the top.

Shelf lengths:

177.5cm
257cm
325cm
356cm
356cm

Not sure how I’ll attach the shelves, but probably with rawl plugs and 4mm screws that are about 8cm deep.

Not sure how thick the wall is, possibly 15-20cm - would it be a good idea to measure using the old holes and checking depth that way? I have a handheld wires and pipes detector.

Because these are bookshelves, I don’t want to pull the wall down! Will it be all right? Probably 100kg - 130kg or so total of books.

Brackets are just angle brackets so upside down L shape.

Bracket spec:

Depth: 38 mm
Height: 300 mm
Width: 250 mm

Any advice would be amazing, thank you!

Edited to include details to answer questions in comments.

Comment: How are the brackets fixed? To what? How is the load applied to the wall? What condition is the wall? How high is the wall? How thick is the wall? What bolts / screws are being used?

Comment: Thanks Mike, so the wall is approx 230cm tall. Wall is in good knick, signs of the previous owner having drilled into it before in multiple places. Not sure how I’ll attach the shelves probably with rawl plugs and 4mm screws that are about 8cm deep. Not sure how thick the wall is, possibly 15-20cm - would it be a good idea to measure using the old holes and checking depth that way? Thanks so!

Comment: (And sorry for the novice questions, new to this!)

Comment: Please [edit] the details into your original post. Not everybody reads comments and comments can get deleted.

Comment: So many pieces of the puzzle in your question - I assume the 14 m (about 45') long shelves will be placed in the attic wall (7.5' height) using 32 brackets, is this description correct? If so, how high are the brackets off the floor? What type of brick - CMU, solid brick or concrete? Are you in an earthquake-active region?

Comment: Thanks R13, so I think the bottom shelf will be quite low at around 35cm from the floor in order to fit the others on the wall.